# Change default llama index gpt base api to internal proxy gpt service

Tags: node.js, llama-index

I'm using LlamaIndex.TS in my node server and I'm trying to change the base url to my proxy azure openAI server, as the following
`process.env['OPENAI_API_BASE'] = 'http://openaiproxy.service.consul:8080/OpenAIProxy/handler';`

It seems the request is still routing to the default.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using  `OpenAIEmbedding` class:

```
...
  // Create Document object with essay
  const document = new Document({text: essay});

  let params = {
    timeout: 20000,
    maxRetries: 1,
    additionalSessionOptions: {
      baseURL: "http://openaiproxy.service.consul:8080/OpenAIProxy/handler",
      defaultHeaders: {
        'X-App-Caller': 'GeniusBotService',
      }
    }
  };
  const serviceContext = serviceContextFromDefaults({
    embedModel: new OpenAIEmbedding(params),
    llm: new OpenAI({model: "gpt-4", ...params})
  });
  // Split text and create embeddings. Store them in a VectorStoreIndex
  const index = await VectorStoreIndex.fromDocuments([document], {serviceContext});
...
```